# Alternative to thermal grease

Tags: cpu

I dont have thermal grease, what is a good alternative?

Years ago I used silver paint and it worked well.

Comment: You might experiment with alternatives, but why take the risk when [thermal paste is cheap](http://www.amazon.com/Arctic-Silver-5-Thermal-Compound/dp/B0002EQU6C/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1304660755&sr=8-3)?

Comment: You're going to risk a $50-300+ part for want of $8 of thermal grease?

Comment: Stephen and Collum, ever consider availability? Maybe that person lives somewhere where thermal paste is not available in stores and they can’t order it online; not everywhere is the United States. Remember, the Internet is *global*.

Comment: There are some *interesting* answers below.  However, without documented proof that they work ***and*** are safe to use, I wouldnt try them unless you accept the risk of damaging your electronics.

Answer (score 4):

Unless it's an emergency just wait until you have thermal paste. If it is an emergency:

Thermal paste mostly works due to the zinc oxide. The best ***TEMPORARY*** fix is to use diaper rash cream from a grocery store.

It's important to remember though that while both products are nearly identical, diaper rash cream has a lot of extra stuff including a higher water content so use just a tiny drop on the end of a toothpick and replace it with real thermal paste ASAP.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best one, but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Toothpaste (non grit) and pencil lead shavings work well together, I got a 10 degree Celsius decrease using this method.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://forums.overclockersclub.com/topic/164465-you-got-your-peanutbutter-on-my-cpu-you-got-your-cpu-in-my-peanut/) tests various **temporary** [thermal interface material (TIM)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005576/processors.html) solutions, some of which cooled better than 8-year-old stock goop:

Degrees Celsius, idle and load in 6 C room:

```
 1. Dielectric Silicone:  22, 34
 2. Liquid Gel Deodorant: 23, 34
 3. Crest Toothpaste:     22, 35
 4. X-Balm Chapstic:      23, 35
 5. Antiseptic Gel:       25, 36 (cools about as well as stock TIM)
 6. High Temp Grease:     23, 38
 7. Hair Molding Clay:    25, 38
 8. Aluminum Foil:        25, 38
 9. Raspberry Preserves:  25, 40+
10. Anti Seize Lubricant: 26, 42
11. No TIM:               27, 45
12. Creamy Peanut Butter: 27, 53
```

In 18 C room:

```
 1. Mayonnaise:           31, 45
 2. Ranch Dressing:       30, 47
 3. Shaving Gel:          33, 47
 4. Easy Cheese:          33, 48
 5. American Cheese:      35, 49
 6. Candle Wax:           33, 51
 7. Chewing Gum:          38, 51
 8. Plastic Wrap:         40, 60
 9. Paper:                38, 72+
10. Duct Tape:            41, 85+
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.overclock.net/cooling-experiments/88633-alternative-thermal-paste.html) seems to suggest some interesting options:

- Cod Liver Oil
- Silver Paint
- Tin Foil
- Liquid Metal

Take these suggestions with a pinch of salt. I'd just order more online.

Comment: "Pinch of salt" here being a figure of speech :-)

Comment: Don't forget JBweld, read an article back before 1ghz processors came out, they found JBweld did a better job than thermal paste, only one problem, it tends to be permanent.

Comment: Actually, tin-foil was the first McGyver solution that popped into my head, but of course, it is essentially pointless because it is solid and thus leaves the air-pockets unaffected, so it is no different that not using it at all. Also, with a thermal conductivity of up to 1,462.5 times that of air, a pinch of salt actually would be practical, literally.

Answer (score 0):

On a recent assembly, my thermal paste was dried up so I ran without. Big No-No.
I was pushing temps of 87 idle topping @ 106 before thermal overload and 
system shutdown.

I did some quick research and decided on 'Anti-Seize' as an alternative mainly because I had it on hand. I've been running for a week now on a 130 watt processor (as of July 29, 2015) with idle temps at 47 C & full load at 58 C.

Published Operating range is 5 - 68.6 C so I can live with those temps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But focus more on answering the question and leave out extraneous information like build parts and cost.